# I'm running a private Geth PoA chain and my signers are failing to start due to a "gap in the chain between ancients". Is there any help I can get?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, genesis, geth-clique, chaindata

So the title doesn't include steps I've tried, given that there are character limits. The long and the short of it is that I'm running a private `geth` PoA chain and my signers/sealers were getting a `Fatal: Could not open database: gap in the chain between ancients [0 - #413583] and leveldb [#413653 - #413652]` error, which led me to try to remove the `leveldb` and `lightchaindata` using `geth --datadir <dir> removedb`, hoping that I can resume the chain from the `ancients` db.

When I try to bring the first signer/sealer online, I get a new error: `Fatal: Failed to register the Ethereum service: database contains incompatible genesis (have XXXX, new XXXX)`

My goal is to attempt to resolve the `gap` by starting the chain back up from the last block in the `ancients` db, accepting that i will have lost the blocks from the `gap` and after. I can't seem to find any documentation or Google results that apply to my particular problem with the `genesis mismatch` and most just refer to running a downstream miner/RPC from mainnet, and flushing the entire `chaindata` directory, then resynching.

Is there a way to correct the `genesis mismatch` issue and resume the chain from the `ancients` db data?

Thanks in advanced!